# Pick a correct overloaded extension method by generic type in the runtime

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I have multiple same extension methods with different generic type

```
public static class ExtA 
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Convert<TQueryType, T>(this IQueryable<TQueryType> source)
        where TQueryType : Personnel where T : IPersonnelView
    {
        //body
    }
}

public static class ExtB 
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Convert<TQueryType, T>(this IQueryable<TQueryType> source)
        where TQueryType : Employee where T : IEmployeeView
    {
        //body
    }
}
```

I can pick the correct extension by sending the different generics

the below code picks the ExtA.Convert() :

```
            return await _context.Personnel.Where(...)
                .Convert<Personnel , IPersonnelView>()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

And this one picks the ExtB.Convert() :

```
            return await _context.Personnel.Where(...)
                .Convert<Employee , IEmployeeView>()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

And everything is ok.

problem :
Now I have ToPagedList method like this :

```
        async Task<PagedList<TResultType>> ToPagedList<TQueryType, TResultType>(
                IQueryable<TQueryType> queryable)
        {
            //Pagging sorting ...

           //error occured here
            queryable.Convert<TQueryType, TResultType>();
        }
```

I got this [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0314?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0314))

> The type 'type1' cannot be used as type parameter 'name' in the
> generic type or method 'name'. There is no boxing conversion or type
> parameter conversion from 'type1' to 'type2

I want to call that in this way

```
ToPagedList<Personnel, IPersonnelView>(query)
```

or

```
ToPagedList<Employee, IEmployeeView>(query)
```

I need a solution to pick the proper extension method without specifying generic types

Comment: I don't think this is easily done, or possible at all.

Comment: There's no direct solution to do this automatically. There are a number of potential workarounds. You could make the caller provide a delegate that calls to the appropriate Convert method. You could use reflection, theoretically, to search through your code base for Convert-like methods. You could call into a service that has all the Convert possibilities pre-registered (like AutoMapper). Each approach has pros and cons.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you've missed `dynamic`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yup, `dynamic` could be nice if the static methods were all put into the same class and had basically the same signature apart from the generic constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the generic parameters has a constraint then the new generic class that uses it must also have the same constraint. As it is stated here:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0314?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0314)]

So, when you call `queryable.Convert<TQueryType, TResultType>();` the method `ToPagedList` must have a constraint like that:

```
async Task<PagedList<TResultType>> ToPagedList<TQueryType, TResultType>(IQueryable<TQueryType> queryable) 
        where TQueryType : Personnel where TResultType : IPersonnelView
```

But, of course that will limit it only to use with the `ExtA.Convert()` method and you will need to add another method `ToPagedList` that will use constraints appropriate for `ExtB.Convert()` (The same way you have multiple `Convert` method with the same signature - as extension methods in separate classes). That will create another problem - code duplication.

The bit better way to solve this issue could be, first - derive `IPersonnelView` and `IEmployeeView` from a common ancestor (e.g. `IView`), and `Personnel` and `Employee`  from another one (e.g. `IPerson`):

```
public interface IView { }
public interface IPersonnelView : IView { }
public interface IEmployeeView : IView { }

public interface IPerson { }
public class Personnel : IPerson { }
public class Employee : IPerson { }
```

Then you can modify the signature of `ToPagedList` in the following way:

```
async Task<PagedList<TResultType>> ToPagedList<TQueryType, TResultType>(IQueryable<TQueryType> queryable) 
        where TQueryType : IPerson where TResultType : IView
```

And you will have to modify the call to the method inside of `ToPagedList` adding the type check:

```
IEnumerable<IView> conversionResult;
if (typeof(TQueryType) == typeof(Personnel))
    conversionResult = ((IQueryable<Personnel>) queryable).Convert<Personnel, IPersonnelView>();
else if (typeof(TQueryType) == typeof(Employee)) 
    conversionResult = ((IQueryable<Employee>) queryable).Convert<Employee, IEmployeeView>();
```

I'd say both of those solutions is far from optimal, however they will do the trick. To find an optimal one, it is likely that you need to refactor a bit the architecture of the program.